# Passed state not changing

Tags: android, ios, react-native, conditional-statements, state

App flow:

ComponentOne:

1. Take photos with phone
2. Send photos to api
3. Navigate to ComponentTwo

ComponentTwo:

4. Render component
5. NOW response from api is received in ComponentOne, after render of ComponentTwo. (Resulting in component not being able to display response since it was received after rendering of component) Desired result is that the loading spinner will spin until response is received from api and when received immediately display it in ComponentTwo.

I am passing state from one component to another, the state, called "loading" starts off as "true" and is supposed to change to "false" when response is received from api, however even though it changes in ComponentOne, ComponentTwo still displays the spinner...

This is how I navigate to second screen and pass the state with it.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ComponentTwo', {loading: this.state.loading});
```

This is how I receive the state and do the conditional rendering, the spinner is supposed to show until the response is received from the api, currently however it just keeps spinning even when data response is received.

```
{
  this.props.navigation.state.params.loading ?
  <Spinner/> :
  <Text>Display response from api when it is received</Text>
}
```

Why does this not work? Why does state not change in second component and render the results, instead it keeps on loading forever. Can you not pass state from one component to another and expect it to change?

**Edit:** "loading" is set to "false" in ComponentOne right after response is received from api, navigation to ComponentTwo happens before this, therefore I want the spinner to show until data is received.

**Edit2:** Anyone know how I can do this using redux? I have redux in the project but don't know how I would do so that `loading` would be set to false when my variable(s) would get a value as response from the api.

Comment: One simple way is to move the data fetching to component two.

Comment: But the photo is sent to api when I take the picture which is in first screen and then the results are displayed in second screen, I don't think I can post in first component and then receive response in second component.

Comment: Can you add the code you use to take picture and sent somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, that navigate params work like react state/ props.
It is a one way street to pass params onto the next screen. These won't update.

You should instead have a component wrapping this two screen that pass props down. THIS will update if you update the state of the wrapper component.

Wrapper could have a state for photo, and once it's updated with the image url it will trigger a rerender and the props will trickle down to the attached components.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean that I should have two classes in one file/component, or two render methods in same component? Can you please explain a bit more about what you meant, thanks.

Comment: I meant, that you create a component that is the parent component of ComponentA and ComponentB and that Wrapper component stores the state of the app and renders componentA & B and passes its state to them as props.

Those components then can have passed changeHandler functions that gets called when the Wrapper state should change.